# How to disconnect from redis using StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm running a long-running executable (about 30 minute sessions), but I only need to write to redis once at the very beginning and once at the end of the session.

Thus, I'd like to disconnect my redis connection after the first write, then reconnect at the end, so that I'm not using a persistent connection for all the time in between when I don't need it.

I'm trying to disconnect by wrapping my logic in a **using** block. However, I get this error (not 100% reproducible, but probably about 50% of the time):

> System.InvalidOperationException: Reading is not allowed after reader was completed. at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.AdvanceReader(SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)

followed by

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
>   at Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.g__ThrowSocketException|10_0(SocketError e)

```
at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at aag.Natives.Api.DeveloperApi.HtmlLogger.ProcessHtmlMessage(DevLogType logType, String message)
at aag.Natives.Api.DeveloperApi.LogError(String message)
at aag.GameServer.EntryPoint.<>c__DisplayClass47_0.<.ctor>b__1(Object s, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e) in E:\dev\LegionTD2_LFS\GameEngine\GameServer\src\GameServer\EntryPoint.cs:line 131
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at DarkRift.ConnectionService.ChunkReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Or is this error benign and should be ignored?

Comment: ConnectionMultiplexer is calling its `Close` method when being disposed and waits for any pending operations to finish, then disconnects from the server(s), so this approach is fine. Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I edited the original post to show the full stack trace.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to `Redis` or `StackExchange.Redis` client, at least not directly. More like a threading issue or network issue, so perhaps you could share some parts of the problematic code? (or use some pseudo-code to show what is happening and when)